# How to find desired data within multiple div in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

this is the html code
i am trying to select data within multiple div tags

```
<div class="details-wrapper apps-secondary-color">
    <div class="details-section metadata">
        <div class="details-section-heading">
         <div class="details-section-contents">
             <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="title">Updated</div>
                 <div class="content" itemprop="datePublished">March 7, 2016</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info meta-info-wide">
<div class="details-sharing-section">
</div>
<div class="details-section-divider"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to select March 7,2016
how can i select this in beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

You can use `soup.find('div', {'itemprop': 'datePublished'})` to select the `div` element with `itemprop` `datePublished`.

**Demo**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''<div class="details-wrapper apps-secondary-color">
    <div class="details-section metadata">
        <div class="details-section-heading">
         <div class="details-section-contents">
             <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="title">Updated</div>
                 <div class="content" itemprop="datePublished">March 7, 2016</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="meta-info">
                 <div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
<div class="meta-info">
<div class="meta-info meta-info-wide">
<div class="details-sharing-section">
</div>
<div class="details-section-divider"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
date = soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'datePublished'})
print(date.text)
```

**Output**

```
March 7, 2016
```

Comment: Thanks...for your answer

Comment: how can i select if there is no itemprop

Comment: Maybe by `class` instead?

Comment: for div above to the class meta-info meta-info-wide

Comment: <div class="meta-info">
<div class="title"> Interactive Elements </div>
<div class="content">Users Interact, Digital Purchases</div>
</div>

Comment: there is nothing unique so how can i select data in this div

Comment: plaese help me in this

Comment: should i update my question because i am unable post question before 90 minutes @gtlambert